# For a non empty finite set A whose all the elements are integers, its supremum and infimum are also integers.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to prove the statement. This is my attempt. Can someone help me with it?

Attempt: 
Proof by contradiction,

Let's say all the elements of A are integers, but supA is not an integer.

Then by approximation property of real numbers, for any $\epsilon$>0, $\exists$ a $\in$ A such that supA- $\epsilon$ < a $\leq$ supA, which tells me that 'a' can be a non-integer, since the choice of $\epsilon$ was arbitrary.

Hence we are done.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

A finite set of numbers will have a largest number and a smallest number. Now, if a set has a largest number, that will be its supremum. So the supremum will be in the set. Same for the infimum. So...

Answer (score 0):

Seems right to me, assuming $A$ is finite. You might want to state more precisely what $\epsilon$ is exactly. You could state this in terms of $\sup(A)-\lfloor\sup(A)\rfloor$, for example. If you choose $\epsilon:=\frac{\sup(A)-\lfloor\sup(A)\rfloor}{2}$, you can be sure that $a\in A$ is chosen from an interval that does not intersect $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How does choosing that $\epsilon$ help us?

Comment: Well, the person that is reading you're proof might not be fully convinced that $a$ cannot be an integer, only because $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary. By being more specifically, you can show there is an $a\in(\lfloor\sup(A)\rfloor,\sup(A)]\cap A$, which yields a contradiction. By the definition of the floor function, $\lfloor\sup(A)\rfloor$ is the largest integer smaller than $\sup(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct. How do you jump from the fact that $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary to the conclusion that $a$ can be a non-integer? Where did you use the fact that $\sup A\notin\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Hi, that was exactly why I did not feel comfortable concluding the proof. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take $\varepsilon=\sup A-\lfloor\sup A\rfloor$. Then$$\sup(A)-\varepsilon<a\leqslant\sup A$$means$$\lfloor\sup A\rfloor<a<\sup A.$$But there is no integer in $\bigl(\lfloor\sup A\rfloor,\sup A\bigr)$.

Comment: Ok, I see what you did. In that case, does this work as well?

If I first prove that supA belongs to the set A, then I am done.

Comment: @Ufomammut Yes, that would work. How do you prove that $\sup A\in A$?

Comment: So for every n>1, there exists an a $\in$ A such that 
sup A - (1/n) < a $\leq$ sup A. Now I will take two elements of the set, let's say a and b and show that |a-b| < 1, but a and b are integers and thus a must be equal to b. So there is only one a that satisfies the relation 
sup A - (1/n) < a $\leq$ sup A
I think, then we are done, right?

Comment: @Ufomammut How did you show that $|a-b|<1$?

Comment: Assuming for every n>1, there exists an a ∈ A such that sup A - (1/n) < a ≤ sup A and for every m>1, there exists a 'b' ∈ A such that sup A - (1/m) < b ≤ sup A. Then, |a-b|=|a-supA + supA-b|< |a-supA|+|b-supA|<(1/n)+(1/m) $\leq$ (1/2)+(1/2) = 1?